# Export AD users with list of specific groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

I've been trying to get an extract of AD users and select `mail`, `name`, `memberof`.  I then need to list only specific groups from the `memberof` output so I end up with a list for each user than contains their name, email address and specific groups that match a certain name and not all of the groups they are a member of.

```psh
Get-ADUser username -Properties memberof | Select-Object memberof
```

I can't seem to find a way of doing this as I end up with either noteproperty above or an empty pipeline.  Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `memberOf` attribute contains a list of `distinguishedName` (DN) values, each corresponding to a group.

Retrieve the groups you are interested in, before you run `Get-ADUser`, that way you can compare the Group DN to the entry in `memberOf`:

```
$GroupDNs = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "*finance*" -or Name -like "*creditcontrol*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
```

Now, you can use those DN's to filter the group memberships with a calculated property, like so:

```
$UserInfo = foreach($username in @("bob","alice","joe")){
    $User = Get-ADUser -Identity $username -Properties mail,memberOf |Select Name,mail,memberof
    $User | Select-Object Name,mail,@{Label="GroupDNs";Expr = {$_.memberof | Where-Object {$Groups -contains $_}}}
}
```

without doing a new `Get-ADGroup` query for each `memberof` entry.

If you want a string of group names, rather than a NoteProperty containing an array of strings, you could fill the Groups into a hashtable and use that to "look up" the `memberof` entries using the `ContainsKey()` method:

```
$Groups = @{}
Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "*finance*" -or Name -like "*creditcontrol*"} | ForEach-Object {
    $Groups[$_.DistinguishedName] = $_
}

$UserInfo = foreach($username in @("bob","alice","joe")){
    $User = Get-ADUser -Identity $username -Properties mail,memberOf |Select Name,mail,memberof
    $User | Select-Object Name,mail,@{Label="Groups";Expr = { ($_.memberof | Where-Object {$Groups.ContainsKey($_)} | ForEach-Object { $Groups[$_].Name}) -join ";" }}
}

$UserInfo | Export-Csv C:\aduserinfo.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: As a side note, if only the group name is of interest, mapping the distinguished name to just the name instead of the whole group object might be preferable.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.  This looks to be just what i need.  I just need to amend the section around foreach($username in @("bob....... as I'll need it to include every AD user.